# The concept of Interfaces applied on location-based apps

Tags: java, android, interface, location

I am new to java interfaces even though I understand the concept, have seen many examples around and know it is preferred over inheritance in some cases because it gives you more flexibility and less dependency.

In practice, I have been building a location-based app for Android for the first time. I feel like I should design some interfaces so I can ease my work in the future, cause I am assuming I'll probably build other location-based apps again.

So I've been trying to build this interface for maps. Currently, I have been using the Mapbox platform instead of Google Maps. I figured that it was a good idea to build an interface in case I want to use Google Maps API in the future.

So I did something like this:

```
public interface Mapable {

    // Marker
    Object createMarker(String id, Location location, int icon);
    void addMarker(Object object);
    void removeMarker(String id);
    void moveMarker(String id, Location destination);

    // Camera
    Object createCamera();
    void addCamera(Object object);
    void changeZoom(int zoom);
    void setZoomRange(int min, int max);
    void moveCamera(Location location, int zoom);

    void updateElements();
}
```

So, I believe it does not matter the platform I want to use, I can make use of this interface to know which methods I must implement in a Map class.

However, it feels like something is missing and its design or purpose is not correct. 
Is this the correct way of using interfaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this the correct way of using interfaces?

Yes! Interfaces can definitely provide more flexibility if you use it like this.

> it feels like something is missing and its design or purpose is not correct.

Maybe you should create an interface called `IMarker` and an interface called `ICamera` instead of using `Object` as markers and cameras?

```
public interface IMarker {
    String getID();
    Location getLocation();
    @DrawableRes
    int getIcon(); // You can also return a Drawable instead, if you want

    // here you can add setters, but I don't think you need to
}

public interface ICamera {
    int getZoom();
    int getMinZoom();
    int getMaxZoom();
    Location getLocation();

    void setZoom(int value);
    void setZoomRange(int min, int max);
    void move(Location location, int zoom);
}
```

Then you can write your `Mappable` interface like this:

```
public interface Mapable {

    // Marker
    IMarker createMarker(String id, Location location, int icon);
    void addMarker(IMarker marker);
    void removeMarker(String id);
    void moveMarker(String id, Location destination);

    // Camera
    ICamera createCamera();
    void addCamera(ICamera camera);
    // Uncomment this line below if you want to be able to get all cameras
    // ICamera[] getCameras();
    // Uncomment this line below if you want to be able to get the current camera
    // ICamera getCurrentCamera();

    void updateElements();
}
```